# Hide Addressbar

Tags: javascript, html

how to hide address bar from popup window opened with window.open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `location` option to toggle the address bar on/off in most browsers:

```
window.open('popup.html', 'popup', 'location=no');
```

If you are aiming for a "visually light weight window" you might also want to disable other visual elements such as `toolbar`, `menubar`, `scrollbars`, `status`:

```
window.open('popup.html', 'popup',
    'location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,status=no');
```

Browsers may or may not choose to follow these directives. See the comprehensive [documentation of the `window.open()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.open) in Mozilla Developer Center for more options and information about support in various browsers.

Comment: Fortunately most popular browsers do conform to this. Jørn, your recommendation 'windowfeature' options is good. +1

Answer (score 4):

On modern browsers this cannot be done, it poses a security risk.

for example:

> In Internet Explorer 7 and later, you cannot remove the address bar in Internet Zone windows, for security (anti-spoofing) reasons. As described in the MSDN article above, in IE7 and later, location=no simply hides the back/forward/stop navigation buttons, and makes the address bar read-only.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are many properties associated with `window.open()` method
Check this is [useful](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml)