# Make address bar read only in window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am opening a window as follows :

```
window.open(url, "_blank", 'toolbar=yes,menubar=no,dialog=yes,maximize=no,top=20,left=165,scrollbars=yes,width=' + width + ',height=' + height + "'");
```

Here I need to make the address bar as read only. I was looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788564/hide-addressbar) but this disables the address bar. However I want it read only.

Comment: how do you see disabled different to read only? (you could set the window color, text color to same as before disabled)

Comment: Sorry, by disabled I meant hidden. I don't want to hide it. Just want to make it read only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that in any browser, use sessions instead to pass values from one page to another so that no one can modify it.

or you can also implement CrossPagePostback concept.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in modern browser. Modern no longer hide the URL bar when location is set to 0. Instead they render it as read only.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1788601/5407188) states the behavior of IE7 regarding this,

> in IE7 and later, location=no simply hides the back/forward/stop
>   navigation buttons, and makes the address bar read-only.

Firefox also behaves the same way. Here is the [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Toolbar_and_chrome_features),

> In Firefox 3, dom.disable_window_open_feature.location now defaults to
>   true, forcing the presence of the Location Bar much like in IE7. See
>   bug 337344 for more information.

I have also tested with Chrome and it also behaves the same way.

So the short answer is "Set location=0 and you can make the URL bar read only".